# Ansible items.key in when condition

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write an Ansible script which will compress files on multiple hosts, based on inventory file. The code and inventory file has given below.

```
tasks:
- name: Create a tar.gz archive of a single file.
  community.general.archive:
    path:
       - "{{items.path}}"
    dest:
       - "{{items.dest}}"
    format: gz
    owner: ubuntu
  become: true
  when:  "{{items.key}} in inventory_hostname"
  with_items:
    - {path: "/var/log/adobe/adobe.log", dest: "/tmp/adobe.log.gz", key: "adobe"}
    - {path: "/usr/local/app/applc.log", dest: "/tmp/applc.log.gz", key: "applc"}
```

inventory file (hosts.ini) contains the hostname.

vm-stg-adobe-201
vm-stg-adobe-202
vm-stg-applc-101

But when I execute the code am getting the below error.

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '{{items.key}} in inventory_hostname' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{items.key}} in inventory_hostname): 'items' is undefined
```

I tried changing items.key as follows but failed.

1. when:  "'items.key' in inventory_hostname"
2. when:  "'{{items.key}}' in inventory_hostname" [when I use this the host key skipped]

Any will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The loop variable is accessed in the task with `item`, not `items`. you should use `{{ item.key }}` (same for dest,path in the other lines)

Comment: I changed to item.path, item.dest, and in when condition I used item.key but still the task is skipped

Comment: for the `when` clause, please see the answer i added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the variable name issue, next task is to make the `when` condition work based on the hostname and the item.key.

Since the hostnames in your inventory have a pattern, the ideal way would be to split the hostname on the `-` delimiter and try to match the 3rd column to the `item.key`. In code, you could do these by:

```
when: inventory_hostname.split('-')[2] == item.key
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to just search if the `inventory_hostname` contains the `item.key`, you can use:

```
when: inventory_hostname is search(item.key)
```

cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the given when condition, but got the error, The error was: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "['/tmp/adobe.log.gz']". Also split  can't be used because some hostnames are not following the patterns

Comment: the `No such file or directory: "['/tmp/adobe.log.gz']"` is problem in your task's logic, but hopefully should be easy to resolve. for the `when`, how do you wish to do the matching? just if the `key` is contained in the inventory_hostname?

Comment: do you have the `/tmp/` directory on the host you get "not found" error? according to the user guide, this is the only requirement (parent dir to exist).

Comment: yes, just the key contained in the inventory_hostname.
/tmp/ directory is present in the host (Ubutnu machine by default it has)

Comment: i am not familiar with this `community.general.archive` module, you could run with `-vvvvv` and see if any useful information shows up. for the matching condition, please see updated answer

Comment: Thanks, ilias-sp for your help on the "when" condition.

Comment: glad these helped @Techiescorner !